# helm hook for both Pod and Job for kubernetes not running all yamls

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs

I am using Kubernetes with Helm 3.

It is ran on CentOS Linux 7 (Core).

K8S (check by running: kubectl version):

git version (kubernetes): v1.21.6, go version: go1.16.9.

helm version: v3.3.4

helm version (git) go1.14.9.

I need to create a Job that is running after a Pod is created.

The pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-mysql
  labels:
    app: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-mysql
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-20"
    "helm.sh/delete-policy": before-hook-creation
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-mysql
      image: {{ .Values.mysql.image }}
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "12345"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: test
```

The Job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-migration-job
  labels:
    app: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-migration-job
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-10"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded, hook-failed
spec:
  parallelism: 1
  completions: 1
  backoffLimit: 1
  template: #PodTemplateSpec (Core/V1)
    spec: #PodSpec (core/v1)
    initContainers: # regular
    - name: wait-mysql
      image: bitnami/kubectl
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      args:
        - wait
        - pod/{{ include "test.fullname" . }}-mysql
        - --namespace={{ .Release.Namespace }}
        - --for=condition=ready
        - --timeout=120s
    containers:
      - name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
        image: {{ .Values.myMigration.image }}
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: {{- toYaml .Values.image.entrypoint | nindent 12 }}
        args: {{- toYaml .Values.image.cmd | nindent 12}}
```

MySQL is MySQL 5.6 image.

When I write the above, also run `helm install test ./test --namespace test --create-namespace`

Even though I changed the hook for pre-install (for Pod and Job), the job is never running.

In both situations, I get messages (and need to press - to exit - I don't want this behavior either:

> Pod test-mysql pending Pod test-mysql pending Pod

> test-mysql pending Pod test-mysql running Pod

> test-mysql running Pod test-mysql running Pod

> test-mysql running ...

In this example, when I put a 'bug' in the Job, for example: `containersx` instead of `container`, I don't get any notification that I have a wrong syntax.

Maybe because MySQL is running (and not completed), can I force to go to the next yaml declared by hook? (Even I declare the proper order for Pod and Job. Pod should run before Job).

What is wrong, and how can I ensure the pod is created before the job? And when the pod starts running, my job will run after that?

Thanks.

Comment: To reproduce your problem -  could you please specify the version of Helm and Kubernetes you are using?

Comment: It is on  CentOS Linux 7 (Core). kubernetes (run: kubectl version): git version (kubernetes): v1.21.6, go version: go1.16.9. helm version: v3.3.4, git version (helm: go1.14.9).
I will put that info on my post.

Comment: Hi, can we use  kubectl commands in `command` section? I tried using mini Kube the Linux commands are working but kubectl and helm commands does not work.

Comment: I used once minicube, and AFAIR it seems that you need to install helm separately as it is not "out of the box". https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your configuration, it looks like you need to set `post-install`  [hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#the-available-hooks) precisely for Job as it should execute after all resources are loaded into Kubernetes. On executing  `pre-install` hook both on Pod and Job, it is run before the rest of the chart is loaded, which seems to prevent Job from starting.

Comment: Do you mean for job I should use only 'post-install'. If I add 'post-install' for pod it run only the hook for the pod (and not any other object, including job), so I should not have 'post-install' for pod. That's because 'post-install' is only after all the objects are installed.